# Can I use PHP reflection to extract function code?

Tags: php, reflection

I am using PHP ReflectionClass to extract as much information about a class as possible. Can I also use this to get return values from functions? Or does that not make sense since reflection only profiles what an object accepts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not rely, if a function has a well defined return value you can simply extract from the source code. Imagine something like this:

```
return $this->isValid() ? $result : $this->createNullObject();
```

Thats hard (/impossible) to parse just to get the return value. You can use DocComments instead. *@return* is the usual tag for that use

```
/**
 * MyMethod
 *
 * @return int
 */
```

Call *getDocComment()* on a *ReflectionMethod*-object and then parse the docComment.

Answer (score 0):

for internal functions you could use

```
$reflect = new ReflectionExtension('standard');
echo "<pre>" . $reflect . "</pre>";
```